# How to draw long aligned arrows like this when defining functions?

Tags: align, function

[image]
[image]

I think it must be some special environments, but I can’t find it. This system also works on longer sequences, so I guess it might be dependent on some diagrams-drawer just like tikz
This could be realized by somehow like “manual measure”, just as a comment suggested, but I believe there are some more convenient ways to do it… 
Thanks for your answers.

Comment: You could insert long space as an argument of a macro, e.g. `\xmapsto{\hspace{5cm}}` ([mathtools](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package).

Comment: @Celdor Thank you for the suggestion but I think it’s not how the author realized that…I will add some new informations.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  I think you got a downvote on this because you only gave us the image and asked us to do all the work.  It would have been nice to at least type out the equations so that we didn't need to do that part, even if you didn't know how to make the arrows.

Comment: I see, actually I just ask for such a template, but not ask other users to make the equations I showed :(. I will notice that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two ways to (almost) do it:

- using amscd
- using tikzcd

Some comments:

- for simplicidty I didn't search for the right representation of Z
- amscd doesen't seem to provide an extendable arrow per se, thought the standard may not be too bad to read
- text from the example is probably too long
- typesetting text and math is a bit ...
- tikzcd puts it as simple as possible (\text{} functionality missing?)

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
 \section{amscd, example from ch. 8 adapted}
 \begin{equation}
  \begin{CD}
    \text{\{Elliptic curves\ } E \text{\ with a quasi-isogeny\ }\alpha \text{:\ } E \rightarrow E_0 \text{\}}
     @>\cong>> 
     \text{\{} \hat Z \text{-lattices in\ } \hat V(E_0) := \text{\dots\}}\\
    E @>>> \hat T(E)
 \end{CD}
 \end{equation} 
 \vspace{2cm}
  \begin{equation}
  \begin{CD}
    S^{{\mathcal{W}}_\Lambda}\otimes T @>j>> T\\
    (S\otimes T)/I @>>> (Z\otimes T)/J
 \end{CD}
 \end{equation} 
\bigskip
 
 
 \section{tikzcd, example from ch. 1.2 adapted}
 \bigskip
 \begin{tikzcd}
 {\{Elliptic\ curves\ E\ with\ a\ quasi-isogeny\ \alpha:\ E\ \rightarrow\ E_0\}} \arrow[r, "\cong"]  & {\{Z-lattices\ \dots\}}\\
E \arrow[r]&  \hat T(E)
 \end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The letters do not matter because I just ask for such a template, I apologize for not making it clear.

Comment: Thank you. No problem

Answer (score 0):

Ok, because you changed your sketch and to make it easier to follow what is or isn't relevant for the code, here's a third way to do it:

- using `tikz`
- and a `matrix`-grid

**What you're after**:

[image: objective]

**Result**, with a minor tpyo:

[image: result]

**Hints**:

- adjust matrix separations pf row and columns as needed
- mixing text with math in the nodes `{ }` may cause some trouble sooner or later
- you can see this when I use `\raisebox` to typeset the exponent `op`
- and also the tiny braces; amsmath's matrix equation will do, but will require using `\text{}` again
- introduce styles for nodes etc. as needed (here: multi-line, and arrow tip)

**Code**:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}% for the set symbols
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
 \section{tikz and matrix}

 \begin{tikzpicture}[%          multiline, change arrow tip
    frm/.style={align=center},
    >=Stealth
 ]
  % ~~~ matrix puts \node s on a grid ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  \matrix[column sep=15mm, row sep=14pt]{
    % ~~~ just regular nodes with some text, w.o. coordinates
    \node[frm]  (A1) {\{Strongly convex rational\\
                      polyhedral cone in\\
                      $(\mathbb{Z}^n)^* \otimes \mathbb{R}$\}}; &
    \node       (A2) {\{Submonoids of $\mathbb{Z}^n$\}\raisebox{1.2ex}{op}}; &
    \node       (A3) {$\mathbf{Sch}_k$}; \\
    
    \node (B1) {$\check \sigma$}; &
    \node (B2) {$\sigma$}; &
    \node (B3) {Spec $k[\sigma] =: U_{\check \sigma}$}; \\
  };
  % ~~~ let's draw some arrows
  \draw[->] (A1) -- (A2);
  \draw[->] (A2) -- (A3);
  \draw[->] (B1) -- (B2);
  \draw[->] (B2) -- (B3);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```